# Is there a way in Notepad++ to use find and replace to find text and then replace text that comes several lines after it?

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I'm currently trying to work my way through a text file where I need to find a specific text string and then replace the line of text that comes several lines after that text string. Here is an example of the text:

```
<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor">
     <SubtypeName>LargeBlockConveyor</SubtypeName>
     <EntityId>111664082437655291</EntityId>
     <Min x="9" y="30" z="7" />
     <BlockOrientation Forward="Right" Up="Up" />
     <ColorMaskHSV x="0" y="-0.8" z="0.2" />
</MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock>
```

In this case I need to search for the string `MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor`, but then I need to actually edit the string `ColorMaskHSV x="0" y="-0.8" z="0.2"`.

The desired result is that everything in each instance of `MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor` would remain the same with the only changes being to the `ColorMAskHSV` line.

In this specific case, everything would stay the same, but the `z="0.2"` would be changed to `z="-0.15"`. Unfortunately, there are also many other variations to the `MyObjectBuilder_`, all of which need to remain unchanged, so I can't just do a find/replace for `z="0.2"`

The intervening lines are unique so they cannot be batch replaced, and there are over 1000 entries like this in the file, so manually editing them would be time consuming to say the least.

Is there a way to create a find and replace expression, or possibly some other tool within Notepad++ that would allow this sort of thing to be streamlined?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: The desired result is that everything in the listed text (all of the unique text / values for each instance of "MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor") would remain the same with the only changes being to the ColorMAskHSV line. In this specific case, everything would stay the same, but the z="0.2" would be changed to z="-0.15". Unfortunately, there are also many other variations to the "MyObjectBuilder_", all of which need to remain unchanged, so I can't just do a find/replace for "z="0.2"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock(?:(?!</MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock>).)+<ColorMaskHSV .+?z="\K[^"]+`
- Replace with: `-0.15`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock          # literally, open tag
                            # Tempered greedy token
(?:                                 # non capture group
  (?!                               # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    </MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock>        #  close tag
  )                                 # end lookahead
  .                                 # any character
)+                                  # end group, must appear 1 or more times
<ColorMaskHSV .+?                   # literally, open tag, followed by 1 or more any character, not greedy
z="                                 # literally
\K                                  # forget all we have seen until this position
[^"]+                               # 1 or more any character that is not double quote (i.e. the value to change)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This worked to seek out every instance of MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock and then change the value of "z=". Unfortunately, I needed only to select those instances where the second half of that line read MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor. I've tried simply substituting MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor for MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock, but the expression did not work as intended and introduced errors into the file. All instances of <MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor">, and only the ones ending in "MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor", to modify the "z=" value.

Comment: To clarify, there are about 7000 MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock instances, but I need to use this expression to select only those which are MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor" instances, of which there are around 1000.

Comment: @SpacedInvader: Just change `<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock` to `<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_Conveyor">` in the `Find what` box.

Comment: Ok, that did get it to work correctly. Thank you very much for the help!